# Neural Network Regularization and derivation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization

I don’t really understand two concepts in Neural Network.

Firstly is the regularization, why the summation is from $l=1$ to $l= L-1$? (highlighted in the photo). I understand if it is from $l=0$ to $l=L-1$, but it starts from $l=1$ which means if we have $4$ layers, we only sum the regularization for $3$ layers.[image]

Secondly, for the derivation of the backpropagation, [image]

I understand the notation $j$ is for next layer and $k$ is the cuerent layer. But what is "p"? and how can the derivation of $W_{jp}$ over $W_{jk}$ become $\delta_{kp}$?

The link for full derivation can be found [here](https://github.com/chrismbryant/backpropagation/blob/master/2017_09_27%20Backpropagation%20Derivation%20(for%20Coursera%20Deep%20Learning).pdf)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The parameters exists between layers, hence the index $L-1$. (Analogy: We have $5$ fingers, and $4$ gaps in between).
- The $p$ index is there for us to carry out matrix multiplication. Recall that to perform matrix-vector multiplication $Ax$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the $i$-th entry is equal to $\sum_{p=1}^n A_{ip}x_p $.
- Notice that we are using partial derivative and hence $\frac{\partial W_{jp}^{[l]}}{\partial W_{jk}^{[l]}} = \begin{cases} 1  &,  p=k\\ 0 &, p \ne k\end{cases}$. Recall that for partial derivative, we treat the other independent variable as a constant, hence differentiating them would give us $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! The $L-1$ does make sense. However, I am still unble to understand the second answer. Though, I don’t understand the second part at all and what does the $\delta = 1$ when $p = k$ and $\delta = 0$ when $k \neq p$. I think I need to review my matrix and rewatch Andrew Ng videos.

Comment: Perhaps want to review some linear algebra and partial derivative. Try to understand $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1}=1, \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1}=0$ might help.

Comment: I do understand how partial differentiation works, It is just normal differentiation based on the variable in the denominator. Though, I don't know how to relate them with the above derivation, probably there is more that I need to understand.

Comment: We can compactly write something like $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}=\delta_{ij}$